# How does an industrial engineer develop a process?

Tags: process-engineering, industrial-engineering, project-management

I would like to know what industrial engineers use for planning and developing a process:

- What is the most widely `business analysis` modeling language used (Think of it as the stage
  consisting of 'How the product is intended to be?')? **(Before the process)**
- What is the type of `software` and what are the `methods` used for `managing` the process? **(Within the process)**

Comment: An engineer is someone who can do for 10 bucks what someone else spends 100 on, but you have to watch the engineer as they will then spend 1000 on improvements ...

Comment: @SolarMike Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @Kais When you ask business analysis, are you asking "should we design x?" Meaning there is a market for x and capital to do so. OR..Here's project X, requirements are Y and budget is Z? (What is the design methodology?)

Comment: @Kais I'm just re-wording your question.

Comment: @GisMofx The second one, but I don't think of it being a design process - but rather, an analysis phase to model the relation between the user and product.

Comment: @GisMofx Can I know if you have any idea?

Comment: This may vary by specific product, but most of the time, mechanical engineers are not modeling the relation between the user and the product at all.  I feel like that would be more of an industrial designer's job.

Comment: It depends what industry they are in. For example in civil aviation, nobody would ever think all this out from first principles. There is a very large document written by the FAA which *tells* you what you need to consider, if you ever want your somebody to actually buy and use your planes or engines. The OP's question sounds much to academic for the real world IMO. (That might be why it gets taught in colleges, of couse...) Oh, and nobody in the real world still uses the Waterfall Model, unless they are planning to go out of business "real soon now." It's at least 20 years behind the curve!

Comment: @DanielKiracofe Ok, Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: @alephzero But any document made by FAA applies to a specific region - What an aviation manufacturer has to do if it wants to sell their products to Europe? It probably won't meet all the requirements of the civil aviation in Germany for example.. Also, if the `Waterfall Model` is not actually used - then, what model is in use? is it the `Agile Model`?

Comment: @DanielKiracofe I updated the question.

Comment: Most manufacturing plants use JIT - well JTFL is also used...

Comment: @SolarMike ok, thanks for the information. But, could you explain how both JIT and JTFL are related to the BA stage?

Comment: in terms of business, JIT is partly about reducing stock levels - check it out...

Comment: @SolarMike I just have checked it, that's why I asked - The context of BA in my question is different from process improvement.

Comment: This question is too full of TLAs.

Comment: That's exactly the point.

Comment: Check sysml which is a extension of uml, PLM is not a model its a management system. Mechanical engineers do not call waterfall watwrfall, nor do they call agile agile (since in fact agile in mechanical engineering is called expensive due to the fact that each release costs a nonrefundable amount of money)

Comment: @joojaa +1 for sysml. But I don't see your point from "Mechanical engineers do not call waterfall watwrfall, nor do they call agile agile".

Comment: @joojaa Also what's the different between a methodology and a management system?

Comment: PLM and PDM are both more like databases and version control than a design methods. Remember a mechanical engineer can not just upload an update. It has to be made that costs money, it has to be shipped, it has to be installed etc.

Comment: @joojaa Do you mean that in ME industry, engineers use PLM/PDM instead of SDLC methodologies such as Agile?

Comment: No i mean PDM/PLM is more like mechanical engineers equivalent to git/subversion.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67936/discussion-between-kais-and-joojaa).

Comment: It's generally not a good idea to use so many acronyms without first defining them.  If you're going to use a term multiple times, acronyms are nice; but the first time you use an acronym it should always be clear what it stands for.  Also all the formatting of specific terms as "code" or whatever the grey area means is really distracting.

Comment: @JMac It has been fixed.

Comment: @SolarMike I merged from https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/17835/how-does-an-industrial-engineer-develop-a-process.

Comment: @Kais What do you consider a modelling language or do you mean software? Ansys, Wolfram Alpha, Python, C++, Basic, Excel.......

Comment: @Kais the question is not related in software development in anyway.

Comment: Talking to yourself now...

Comment: @SolarMike I mean the software tool used by an industrial engineer, to manage the process, workflow, working methodology, management system, business analysis, system engineering, quality management.

Comment: What do you use? What field are you in? If you give some indication we may be able to supply better information. As the packages I have already listed can do most, if not all, the examples you listed...

Comment: @SolarMike OK. What can do Basic for a car development process, then?

Comment: So "What do you use" and "what field are you in" - not answered - as for Basic - it depends what program has been written and the result will depend on the data and its quality...

Comment: @SolarMike what field I'm in: computer hardware and robotics. what I use: solidworks for cad modeling, Python for programming. but need tools for process engineering and business modeling.

Comment: you can model a business in excel - just depends what data you have and what you want : the solver is fantastically powerful...

Comment: @SolarMike What about the methodologies? shall I use VE(Value Engineering)?

Comment: Use the solver : as to value, that depends on what you class as valuable : money, time, materials......

Comment: @SolarMike OK. Will PLM be helpful for the process?

Comment: @GlenH7 Now that I have made my question clear as it is intended to be - please undo the hold.

Comment: This question is still a poll and overly broad - it's not a good fit for this site.

Comment: @GlenH7 Why do you think it is poll and not suitable for the website? What is the basis of the claim?

Comment: @Kais Have a look at the [Help Center's 'Don't Ask' section](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), and in particular the second and third bullets under "**To prevent...**"

Comment: @GlenH7 OK, then what indicates that my 'answer is provided along with the question'?

Comment: @GlenH7 Concerning the 3rd bullet - does asking for information rather than problem solving, make my question inappropriate?

Comment: @Kais - Both of your bullet points are asking for lists of items, which is what makes this a poll-type question.  The other challenge with this question is that you're assuming that you can overlay techniques from one branch of engineering (software development) onto another branch (mechanical engineering).  It's a flawed premise and the sheer number of comments on this question should have been a sign that something was wrong.

Comment: @GlenH7 Ah ok, I understood. Thanks for the clarification. Now, what about the last edit?

Comment: @Kais - When a question is edited after is has been placed on hold, it goes into a review queue to see if it should be re-opened.  So the community then votes on the revised question.  And I have been trying to think of ways to edit this so it fits within the guidelines.  I don't think there's an answer to your question though.  I have worked with a number of disciplines, and my primary experience is SW across a number of industries.  I really haven't noticed a de facto set of tools that are consistently used.

Comment: @GlenH7 Ok thanks for letting me know. no problem though .. I think SysML, PDM/PLM/MPM SW, SciPy(useful for DMAIC) and Excel Solver are what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SysML is a good choice when it comes to modeling use cases and understanding systematic approach (business modeling), in a generic industrial context.

SQL is used to mine business data. R is great for analysis and simulation.  VBA has good portability when coupled with Excel.

PDM software is good for setting up a document control process. Checking files into a database, monitoring revisions, and controlling the approval process, of BOM's (bill of materials) (Product Lifecycle Management (PLM)).

Comment: I added a paragraph to address your modelling concerns.

Comment: ok thanks for the update. Sounds more clear now.

Comment: What's the advantage of these math/statistical tools compared to SysML?

Comment: What methodologies need to be involved within the process?

Comment: I’ve never used SysML.  I have a mechanical engineering background with experience in Simulink.  Either system is a GUI to model a system, do the Laplace transforms to end up with a transfer function.  Then create control plots.  I’m not sure if how many resources SysML has for community support.  I do know Simulink has a robust community network.

Comment: Note control charts I meant bode diagrams

Comment: OP is talking of more early stage of modeling than you are, like before final architecture or even what the thing would do. Sysml does not really aim to be a calculation model altough it can be used that way, more like a formalized way to to abtractions of your ideas.